# SSL Handshake failed on Android 6

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I need to get a content from website through https connection. I have used the below code to connect the website with desktop application but its getting failed on Android 6. I have searched for many days however found no result(I tried to add intermediate CA and root CA but the same result). Please anyone help me out.

```
String url = "https://www.coles.com.au";
try{
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                    (HttpsURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            while(null != (content = reader.readLine())){
                System.out.println(strStoreList);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            String exception = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
```

Above code ends up with SSL handshake exception - handshake failed thrown out.